# Validate JSON Using OpenAPI Schema in VS Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, openapi, jsonschema

I have a static API which consists of just 3 JSON files.
I'm using JSON Schema to validate these files in VS Code today.
My VS Code workspace is set up like this:

```
"settings": {
    "json.schemas": [
      {
        "fileMatch": ["/deploy/materials.json"],
        "url": "./schema-materials.json"
      },
      {
        "fileMatch": ["/deploy/lightsources.json"],
        "url": "/schema-lightsources.json"
      },
      {
        "fileMatch": ["/deploy/cameras.json"],
        "url": "/schema-cameras.json"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Now I want to migrate this to a single OpenAPI Schema file instead. How would I go about setting up VS Code so it understands that there's 3 different endpoints specified in the schema and to validate the 3 JSON files separately against it?

I imagine my workspace like this after the change:

```
"settings": {
    "json.schemas": [
      {
        "fileMatch": ["/deploy/materials.json"],
        "url": "./openapi.json"
      },
      {
        "fileMatch": ["/deploy/lightsources.json"],
        "url": "/openapi.json"
      },
      {
        "fileMatch": ["/deploy/cameras.json"],
        "url": "/openapi.json"
      }
    ]
  }
```

How do I set up my workspace and/or openapi.json so they can validate?
Here's a snippet from my openapi.json schema file:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.1.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Physically Based API",
    "description": "A database of physically based values for CG artists.",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "contact": {
      "name": "Anton Palmqvist",
      "url": "https://physicallybased.info/about/"
    },
    "license": {
      "name": "CC-BY-SA-4.0",
      "url": "https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode"
    }
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "https://api.physicallybased.info/"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/materials": {
      "get": {
        "tags": ["Materials"],
        "description": "Gets a list of materials.",
        "operationId": "getMaterials",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "limit",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "limit the amount of results returned",
            "required": false,
            "schema": {
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int64"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Material"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

I've tried creating an openapi.json schema and specifying it in my VS Code workspace settings as the JSON schema validator, but I don't know how make it interpret the single-file schema.